# Force load() wait for doucment.ready at remote URL

Tags: jquery

In looking at this page: 
http://reviews.econcept.biz/new-american-funding-954499264

The business "new american funding" wishes to grab the reviews and show them on one or more of there local web properties.

The DIV that contains the aggregated reviews is: `#allReviews`

However, it appears that particular div's content is dynamically generated since a .load() call produces only that requested div but empty content.

`$('#revcontainer').load("http://reviews.econcept.biz/new-american-funding-954499264 #allReviews");`

I'm assuming that with async issues that is why i'm not getting the content along with the div in question and for what i can find .load() cannot be made "synchronous". How can we scrape that div and content successfully?

Comment: `load()` will grab the static content available at a web address; it won't run any Javascript, etc. that might load extra content. Apart from that, I have to wonder if automatically loading and displaying reviews from a third-party site is a good move. What happens when negative reviews inevitably appear?

Comment: @PaulRoub normally I would agree, but the value in this to the company is that the econceptt.biz provider has built a fairly robust "aggregator" script, grabbing reviews from over 25 properties. The value outweighs that risk. Besides - everyone should expect a "occasional" bad review, brings balance and validity :)

Comment: Target directly relevant URL with relevant parameter, e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/75LzqxzL/

Comment: @A.Wolff "New American Funding" is a random example from there database, the one relevant to me is "http://reviews.birdeye.com/ray-french-air-conditioning-heating-inc-402583744" and the API method they have and you use in the jsfiddle doesn't seem to work on all there listings, I was aware of it, but unable to get it to work for RayFrench AC.

Comment: With this URL http://reviews.birdeye.com/papi/reviews-ajax/businessid/402583744/status/2?&stype=bzsite&op=3&sindex=0&count=25&rc=14 works as expected. I'm really not sure to see what you are looking for exactly

Comment: @A.Wolff you know man, I kid you not, I tried this identical thing Friday repeated times and it would not return the content, and yet -- here it works now. Well, All I can say is thanks Wolff.